# SQL Merge Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to use the new "MERGE" statement in SQL Server 2008. The statement will get records from a temporarty table and update the same in some other table.The statement is as following:

```
create table #TempTable(ProcPOAmdDel_ProcessAmendmentId bigint,ProcPOAmdDel_SemiFinProdId bigint,ProcPOAmdDel_ChallanQty int)

MERGE PurProcessPOAmendmentDelivery AS pod
USING (SELECT ProcPOAmdDel_ProcessAmendmentId,
       ProcPOAmdDel_SemiFinProdId FROM #TempTable ) AS temp
ON pod.ProcPOAmdDel_ProcessAmendmentId = temp.ProcPOAmdDel_ProcessAmendmentId AND 
   pod.ProcPOAmdDel_SemiFinProdId=temp.ProcPOAmdDel_SemiFinProdId 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET pod.ProcPOAmdDel_ChallanQty = temp.ProcPOAmdDel_ChallanQty;
```

While running the state I encountered an error Invalid column    name'ProcPOAmdDel_ChallanQty'.

Could anybody help me in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Include column ProcPOAmdDel_ChallanQty in Source table i.e. temp

```
MERGE PurProcessPOAmendmentDelivery AS pod
USING (SELECT ProcPOAmdDel_ProcessAmendmentId,
              rocPOAmdDel_SemiFinProdId,
              ProcPOAmdDel_ChallanQty
       FROM #TempTable ) AS temp
ON pod.ProcPOAmdDel_ProcessAmendmentId = temp.ProcPOAmdDel_ProcessAmendmentId AND 
pod.ProcPOAmdDel_SemiFinProdId=temp.ProcPOAmdDel_SemiFinProdId 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET pod.ProcPOAmdDel_ChallanQty = temp.ProcPOAmdDel_ChallanQty;
```