# Linq to Sql check if multiple records exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

When using Linq to Sql  and updating something like a cross reference table where they could already be records in the table that would just need to stay there, records that will change and records that could be removed. What is the best practice as to handle this? I am thinking delete all and recreate. Is that bad?

Should I delete the reference records and repopulate all of them. Naturally removing what is no longer needed and creating what is needed.

or

Should i attempt to perform some type of check and remove what is old with what is being added

or

what is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to SQL is not the best tool for scenario's like this.

Basically you will have to write update/insert/delete all by yourself. You can use the exists() any() etc. to create the sets, but the resulting SQL will be all individual inserts, updates.

It is query language after all.

In your case, I would do a merge through a stored procedure and call that.

Comment: Thank you, that is what i figured but i wanted to make sure I was right.

Answer (score 1):

A MERGE statement ([StackOverFlow Merge Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207935/sql-merge-statement)) might work out best in this situation. It will allow for multiple rows to be manipulated at the same time at your discretion.

Comment: If it was T-sql of course!! but This is Linq to SQl. You have to use linq to perform the query.  Do you know a way of doing that in Linq?